# How to draw a rectangle from UIViewCotroller in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone

I am having a UIView and a UIViewContorller to that. I want to draw a rectangle in the view through my controller. So how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a subview to your view controller's view in viewDidLoad and set the background color to whatever color you want, provided that all you need is a solid color rectangle.

Comment: This is by far the easiest method.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, if you just need a static rectangle you could use an imasge and use UIImageView to display it where you need. If you need to draw it go to this faq
https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/GraphicsAndAnimation/#2D-DRAW_LINES__CIRCLES__POLYGONS__AND_BEZIER_PATHS  and then to the programming guide to drawing on the iphone, theres some helpful projects they provide to help you out as well.